# How to make JSON from a DataTable with variables as Key

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

I have a query from a database with many rows stored in a DataTable.

I have 40 ID's but each ID has 300 rows. 
The data looks like this:

[image: DataTable data]

I want to serialize this from the DataTable as JSON with `ID` and `F_SD` as a key.

After serializing the DataTable I get JSON looking like this:

[image: undesirable JSON]

Can anyone help me with this? 
I will use this data at frontend for a js graph. 
I want something like:

```
{
    "ID": {
        "f_sd1": {
            "value": 1.555
        }
        "f_sd2": {
            "value": xxxx
        }
    }
    "nextID": {
        "f_sd1": {
            "value": 1.555
        }
        "f_sd2": {
            "value": xxxx
        }
    }
}
```

I am serializing it like this right now:

```
using (con = new OracleConnection(constr))
{
    using (cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt1);                    
        var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt1, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });

        return Content(list, "application/json");                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code (see [mcve]) so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: I added code where i serializing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq methods to group the rows of your `DataTable` into an anonymous object structure and then serialize that:

```
    var obj = dt1.Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .GroupBy(row => (int)row["ID"])
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                      g => g.ToDictionary(row => (int)row["F_SD"],
                                          row => new { value = (decimal)row["VAL"] }));

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);

    return Content(json, "application/json");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zWIUZ5

Answer (score 2):

try:

`using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter`

```
 using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; )
     {
        writer.WritePropertyName(table.Rows[i]["ID"]);
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        DataRow[] idsMatch = table.Select("ID = "+table.Rows[i]["ID"])+"");]

        foreach(DataRow row in idsMatch)
        {
          writer.WritePropertyName("f_sd"+row["F_SD"]);
          writer.WriteStartObject();
          writer.WritePropertyName("value");
          writer.WriteValue(row["VAL"]);
          writer.WriteEndObject();
          i++;
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's looking good in debug. But how to return it? when I am returning it is showing "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'". Any ideas to resolve?

Comment: writer.ToString() should do the work, you'll may be needed to add writer.WriteStartObject() and writer.WriteEndObject() at the start and end respectively to wrap it all up as one JSON object.

Comment: writer.ToString() not working. It show only some properties of writer not result data. If i return StringBuilder it shows data but not like json and with many double quotes and backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make a dictionary object from your data table.
2- Add newtonsoft package with nuget by 'Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json'
3- Then use JsonConvert.SerializeObject method like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionaryObject);
```

Comment: I tried dictionary but still i get error: "An item with the same key has already been added." I think its because same ID is on many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking about list? If so Create your DataModel like this

```
 public class DataModel
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public List<string> fid{ get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }      
        }
```

Then Serialize your Object using NewtonSoft Json

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataMOdel))
```